# Is "Race against the time" a well established motto?

Tags: idioms

According to ["Your Time Starts Now"](http://books.google.com/books?id=IkTQL-Ofc4MC&pg=PT74&dq=%22against%20the%20time%22&hl=it&sa=X&ei=85XuUYW3H-eu4ATxtYC4DQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22against%20the%20time%22&f=false) by Dr. Vijay Agrawal, it seems that "Race against the time" is a well established motto.

> Today 'Race against the time' is the motto of success and the
>   parameter of ability. The expertise of a reporter is evaluated on the
>   basis of getting such a news item first, '**Maharashtra's** chief
>   minister has been asked to submit his resignation.'

In that book, however, the author also uses "run against the time", whose meaning is perfectly understandable but it doesn't appear so common in the English language, at least in written texts.

So, my question is, are "Race against the time" or "Running against the time" well established mottoes?

For what is worth, a quick searching on Google shows that one can run against "the clock", rather than against "the time". Nevertheless, how can the *clock* version and the *time* version lead to different interpretations? What are the reason why one should be preferred on the other, if any?

Answer (score 5):

While "race against the time" isn't a particularly common idiom as far as I know, and it sounds strange to me, there is a very similar phrase that *is* common, which is "a race against time" (without the "the").

The [FreeDictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/race+against+time), borrowing from the McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs, defines it as:

> 1. a rush; a rush to beat a deadline. *We were in a race against time to beat the deadline. It was a race against time, but we made it.*

Which seems to mean what you want.

Comment: Yes, +1, but is it possible that the "the" is dropped there because "time" in that context is a mass noun?

Comment: Quite likely. We're not talking about a specific time (i.e. *three o'clock*) but about the inexorable march of time.

Comment: @Carlo_R., no, it isn’t just because ‘time’ is a mass noun. It is because time is always referred to without an article when the notion of time itself (as opposed to a specific point in time), just like ‘space’. You would also not say ‘the time is running out’ or ‘the time heals’. A mass noun cannot be _counted_, but it can be made _definite_; for example, ‘furniture’ is a mass noun, but you can say, “The furniture arrives tomorrow”.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I would *call race against time* a motto; it's just an expression similar to *race against the clock*. You could call it a cliché on the other hand.

Comment: So, "race against the time" and "race against the clock" are both idiomatic English?

Comment: @Carlo_R., no—see Avner’s reply. ‘Race against the clock’ is idiomatic, and ‘race against time’ is idiomatic; but not ‘race against the time’.

Comment: Yes, except the expression, as noted in the other answer, is race against time, without the use of the word 'the'.

Comment: Carlo, “race against the time” is non-standard and not idiomatic.  “Race against the clock” is not idiomatic, but just a phrase that means what it says.

Comment: @jwpat7, unless you are actually trying to see whether you or a clock can move faster down a running track, I’d say ‘race against the clock’ is idiomatic.